# Get list of registered or enqued styles? looking for filters or actions

Tags: css, filters, actions

Where can I get the list of styles about to be printed?  What i want is to either filter the list, doing what i want with each, then return empty list.  Or do an action that recieves the list, then i can remove_action the print_styles.  Something like that, anyway.  I'm creating a css minifier concatenizer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a global variable named `$wp_styles`. It is a `WP_Styles` object (if it exists at all) and it holds all the enqueued styles in a public variable `$queue`.

Untested:

```
global $wp_styles;

if ( is_a( $wp_styles, 'WP_Styles' ) )
{
    print_r( $wp_styles->queue );
}
else
{
    print 'no styles enqueued';
}
```

Make sure you test that *after* the `init` hook, because stylesheets should not be enqueued earlier.

For details see:

- `/wp-includes/functions.wp-styles.php`,
- `/wp-includes/class.wp-styles.php` and
- `/wp-includes/class.wp-dependencies.php`

Comment: Beauty.  Also, for realted searches, the $wp_scripts works in the same way.  So, for concatenizing and minifying purposes, it looks like I can simply go thru the $wp-styles->enqued array, do the concat/min on those files and then swap out my resulting min.css in the ->registered and ->enqued arrays. Problems or thoughts?